# Bootstrap col and col-offset for center align and spanning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, col

I expect the code to center align my content for all devices and the size of the form group to be 4, 6 and 12 for large, medium and small, and extra small. But it is not rendering properly.

```
<div id="user" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group  col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
                <label for="userType"> I WOULD LIKE TO REGISTER AS A </label>
                <select id= "userType" class="form-control" formControlName="userType" style="height:34px" >
                    <option value="Customer">CUSTOMER</option>
                    <option value="Dealer">DEALER</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group  col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
                <label for="userName"> USER NAME</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" formControlName="userName" >
                <div class="alert alert-danger " *ngIf="signUpForm.get('userName').touched && signUpForm.get('userName').invalid">
                    <div [hidden]= "!signUpForm.get('userName').hasError('required')">
                    Please enter your name
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group  col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
                <button (click)="userFunction()" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right" [disabled]= "!((signUpForm.get('userType').dirty && signUpForm.get('userType').valid) && (signUpForm.get('userName').dirty && signUpForm.get('userName').valid)) " >NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might wanna post the HTML output i.e. the ones with all Angular code rendered into normal HTML. Makes troubleshooting a lot easier.

Comment: i dont have previlege to add images :(

Comment: What images?? I was talking about HTML `code`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the following markup.

Breakdown:

- `.form-group` is already a component that stacks into a column, so you do not need to wrap each of them into `.row > .col-lg-12`s.
- As there is just one column, you can define it once at the top, with `col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4`, and make sure it is centered by adding `.justify-content-center` to the main `.row`.
- Also, the first `.row` should be within a `.container` or a `.container-fluid` to avoid the horizontal scrollbar.

```html
<div id="user" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Using `.justify-content-center` to center cols in the row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- Using just one `.col-12 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4` as `.form-groups` are already stacking into a column -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userType"> I WOULD LIKE TO REGISTER AS A </label>
                <select id= "userType" class="form-control" formControlName="userType" style="height:34px" >
                    <option value="Customer">CUSTOMER</option>
                    <option value="Dealer">DEALER</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName"> USER NAME</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" formControlName="userName" >
                <div class="alert alert-danger " *ngIf="signUpForm.get('userName').touched && signUpForm.get('userName').invalid">
                    <div [hidden]= "!signUpForm.get('userName').hasError('required')">
                    Please enter your name
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <button (click)="userFunction()" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right" [disabled]= "!((signUpForm.get('userType').dirty && signUpForm.get('userType').valid) && (signUpForm.get('userName').dirty && signUpForm.get('userName').valid)) " >NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```